# Off-diagonal elements of the metric tensor and reversal symmetries

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

Given a metric that may be written as in some suitable coordinate system as $g_{\mu0}=\delta_{\mu0}$ and arbitrary other components, what properties of the spacetimes described by this kind of metric can be inferred?

I presume one limitation it gives is that this type of metric may only belong to a spacetime that is time-reversal symmetric. Are there other limitations or, if I am free to choose the other elements of the tensor, could this metric belong to any spacetime with time-reversal symmetry?

More generally, does  a constraint like above but with a different index (e.g. $g_{\mu1}=\delta_{\mu1}$) then analogously imply a spatial reversal symmetry? And consequently, is a metric diagonalisable if (and only if?) it has such  a symmetry for every dimension?

Answer (score 0):

**Q**: Is a metric diagonalisable if it can be written as $g_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu}$?

**A**: Yes. In fact, a metric is real and symmetric by definition so it is diagonalisable no matter what.

**Q**: Is a metric diagonalisable only if it can be written as $g_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu}$?

**A**: No. The Schwarzchild metric is diagonalisable (as described above) but it has curvature which the delta metric does not.

**Q**: Is a metric diagonalisable only if it can be written as $g_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\mu\nu}$ *at a point*?

**A**: Still no because metrics for space-time rather than just space are diagonalisable but they contain eigenvalues of both signs. So one can at most hope to write them as $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}$ at a point.

**Q**: Is a metric diagonalisable only if it can be written as the flat metric appropriate for its signature at a point?

**A**: No and again Schwarzschild provides a counter-example. At the horizon radius $r = 2m$, one of the eigenvalues is zero meaning there is no change of co-ordinates which can rescale it back to $\pm 1$. Nothing unusual happens here if we look at invariant quantities so this is only an artifact of our description. Co-ordinate singularities like this are common because most manifolds cannot be covered by a single co-ordinate patch. A more drastic singularity occurs at $r = 0$ signalling the need for some new physics.

**Q**: Is a metric diagonalisable only if it can be written as the flat metric appropriate for its signature at a non-singular point?

**A**: Yes and this is a theorem. Namely, the existence of [normal co-ordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates).

None of these statements make reference to time reversal. To do that, we need the space-time manifold to be orientable. When it is, gravity on its own [respects time reversal invariance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288339/does-gravity-break-time-reversibility-on-the-microlevel) but other theories that we couple to it (or place on the ambient space-time) might not.